# Sort array in Alphabetical order in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an `arraylist` of states where the statename are not displaying in `Alphabetical` order. I want to display the same in `ALPHABETICAL` order. Below is the code

```
string[] allStates = dsUserGroups
  .Tables[2]
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(r => r.Field<string>("BOUNDARY_VALUE"))
  .ToArray();

ViewState["States"] = string.Join(",", allStates);
```

Comment: Add `.OrderBy(...)` before `.ToArray()`?

Comment: Note that you have an array, not an [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0).

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: so can't I arrange it alphabetically ?

Comment: No, you can do as @user16606026 said to sort the items, but you should also use the correct names for things when talking about them since otherwise it can get confusing for those of us reading.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: trying like this but giving error `string[] allStates = dsUserGroups.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("BOUNDARY_VALUE")).OrderBy("ASC").ToArray();`  Error **C# type arguments cannot be inferred from usage**

Comment: Suggested reading: [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-8.0).  Dont guess or assume arguments, usage or syntax.  It is truly trivial to look it up and eliminate doubt and uncertainty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you almost had it in the comments. OrderBy is automatically acesnding, so you dont have to add "ASC". The OrderBy wants to know by what criteria it should be sorted, so usually its something like:

```
OrderBy(obj => obj.attribute)
```

Since you want to sort the strings themselves they only need to "reference themselves".
So:

```
OrderBy(str => str)
```

If we now add this to your code snippet we get this:

```
string[] allStates = dsUserGroups.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("BOUNDARY_VALUE")).OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
ViewState["States"] = string.Join(",", allStates);
```

Comment: You are very much welcome ^^ @hud

Comment: The new `.Order()` is the equivalent of `.OrderBy(s => s)`